# a dependency to be in classpath only if run a plugin

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

For development I run application using jetty through maven (jetty-maven-plugin) and for all other deployments  I use tomcat, 
I want jetty  web-socket(javax-websocket-server-impl) libs   added to the classpath  on if I run my app using jetty maven plugin, in tomcat these are inbuilt so I need  not tell maven to grab these libs.

so to restrict these libs only for jetty maven plugin I added these libs inside 
jetty-maven-plugin

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jetty.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webAppConfig>
                        <contextPath>/myproject</contextPath>
                    </webAppConfig>
                </configuration>
                 <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                          <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
                          <artifactId>javax-websocket-server-impl</artifactId>
                          <version>9.1.0.v20131115</version>
                        </dependency>
                 </dependencies>            
            </plugin>
```

this should add the jetty websocket libs to the classpath only if I run the plugin, but Its not,and I keep   getting class not found,  and if I add this to main dependencies in the pom it works,  but i cannot do this because I dont want jetty libs in my deployment file when deployed in tomcat,  please correct me, tell me how to restrict these libs only to the execution of this plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dependency will only be available for the plugins execution, not for the application. From the [pom plugin documentation](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugins):

> **dependencies:** Dependencies are seen a lot within the POM, and are an element under all plugins element blocks. The dependencies have the same structure and function as under that base build. The major difference in this case is that instead of applying as dependencies of the project, they now apply as dependencies of the plugin that they are under. The power of this is to alter the dependency list of a plugin, perhaps by removing an unused runtime dependency via exclusions, or by altering the version of a required dpendency.

You can use [profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) instead, to add the dependency to the class path dependencies when running on the development machine.